# Keras custom loss function: The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [4]

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm trying to make a custom loss function for a Keras model. However I get this error that I have absolutely no idea what it means.

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [4,1]

```
def MyLossTennis(yTrue, yPred):
    noBet = yTrue[:, 0:1]
    favWon = yTrue[:,1:2]
    dogWon = yTrue[:, 2:3]
    
    noBetOdds = yTrue[:, 3:4]
    favOdds = yTrue[:, 4:5]
    dogOdds = yTrue[:, 5:6]
    
    noBetCastka = 0
    favCastka = 1000
    dogCastka = 1000

    def NoBet():
        return K.concatenate([0 * noBet, 0 * noBet, 0 * noBet]) * yPred
    def FavWon():
        return K.concatenate([0 * noBet, favWon * favOdds, -1000 * noBet]) * yPred
    def DogWon():
        return K.concatenate([0 * noBet, -1000 * noBet, dogWon * dogOdds]) * yPred
    
    return (tf.switch_case(tf.cast(tf.argmax([noBet, favWon, dogWon]), tf.int32), branch_fns={0: NoBet, 1: FavWon}, default=DogWon))
```

```
Epoch 1/100000
2023-03-15 01:09:00.979547: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [4,1]
         [[{{node MyLossTennisPokus/switch_case_1/indexed_case/MyLossTennisPokus/strided_slice_2/_26}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/aux/CreateModels.py", line 875, in <module>
    CreateModel(ModelLolTennis)
  File "/aux/CreateModels.py", line 704, in CreateModel
    FitModel(model, ModelParams, ModelData)
  File "/aux/CreateModels.py", line 157, in FitModel
    model.fit(modelData["xTrain"], modelData["yTrain"], epochs=modelParams["epochs"], verbose=modelParams["testModelVerbose"], batch_size = modelParams["batchSize"], validation_data=(modelData["xVal"], modelData["yVal"]), callbacks=callbacks)
  File "/home/au/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/au/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 52, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

The second input must be a scalar, but it has shape [4,1]
         [[{{node MyLossTennisPokus/switch_case_1/indexed_case/MyLossTennisPokus/strided_slice_2/_26}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1210]
```

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68729354/the-second-input-must-be-a-scalar-but-it-has-shape-14-16-16-tensorflow-cust), I think *all* things in the loss function must be differentiable. Can you try moving `def NoBet()` and other functions outside and try again?

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu This is why I use `tf.switch_case` instead of regular if/else, tf.switch_case is supposed to be differentiable.